# Reading the Date from div

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, countdown

I'm making a web page and I have to make a countdown that read the date from a div (the div read the date from database).

When it takes the string, it behaves as it has not read my input date, although it reads the famous "1 january 1970".

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">

        var gcor = new Date();
        var dscad = new Date(document.getElementById("caramello"));
        var difftempo = (dscad - gcor) / 1000;
        var minuto = 60;
        var ora = 60 * 60;
        var giorno = 60 * 60 * 24;
        var giorest = Math.floor(difftempo / giorno)
        var orerest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno) / ora)
        var minrest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno - orerest * ora) / minuto)
        var secrest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno - orerest * ora - minrest * minuto))

        ID = window.setTimeout("update();", 1000);

        function update() {
            gcor = new Date();
            difftempo = (dscad - gcor) / 1000;
            minuto = 60;
            ora = 60 * 60;
            giorno = 60 * 60 * 24;
            giorest = Math.floor(difftempo / giorno)
            orerest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno) / ora)
            minrest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno - orerest * ora) / minuto)
            secrest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno - orerest * ora - minrest * minuto))

            document.getElementById("Label1").innerText = giorest;
            if (giorest < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Label2").innerText = "0" + orerest;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Label2").innerText = orerest;
            }
            if (minrest < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Label3").innerText = "0" + minrest;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Label3").innerText = minrest;
            }
            if (secrest < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Label4").innerText = "0" + secrest;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Label4").innerText = secrest;
            }
            ID = window.setTimeout("update();", 1000);
        }
```

and this is the **html/asp** that is linked with it:

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
<div>
    <div id="caramello" onclick="prova();">18 july 2013</div><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>g
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>h
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>m
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="00"></asp:Label>s
</div>
    </form>
```

Comment: use `document.getElementById("caramello").innerText`

Comment: @nrodic I use ".innerHTML" but I'm seeing that the code doesn't arrive at the function upgrade()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YTAXM/

```
<div id="caramello">July 18 2013</div>
<br />
<br />
<div ID="Label6"></div>
<br />
<div ID="Label1">00</div>g
<div ID="Label2">00</div>h
<div ID="Label3">00</div>m
<div ID="Label4">00</div>s

var dscad = new Date(document.getElementById("caramello").innerHTML);

function update() {

    var gcor = new Date();
    difftempo = (dscad - gcor) / 1000;
    minuto = 60;
    ora = 60 * 60;
    giorno = 60 * 60 * 24;
    giorest = Math.floor(difftempo / giorno)
    orerest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno) / ora)
    minrest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno - orerest * ora) / minuto)
    secrest = Math.floor((difftempo - giorest * giorno - orerest * ora - minrest * minuto))

    document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = giorest;

    document.getElementById("Label2").innerHTML = orerest;

    document.getElementById("Label3").innerHTML = minrest;

    document.getElementById("Label4").innerHTML = secrest;
}



setInterval(function () {
     update();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I would accept the other answer over mine.  I was trying to stick as close to the OP's code as possible, but Daniel's answer is cleaner and better practice.

Answer (score 2):

why are you trying to read from the div?
you could write a simple method which gets the end date of the countdown and trigger this function with setInterval (obviously better in your case).
this function just writes the remaining time to your div.
reading from the ui - especially in your case from a static element like a div - is mot a good practice.
the dom should be only written from the code.

-- edit: add a code example on jsfiddle
I added a code example on jsfiddle to clarify my answer
http://jsfiddle.net/FphCm/1/

```
// html
<div id="Count"></div>

// script
var gcor = new Date(2013,12,31); // end date

var update = function() {
var temp = new Date();
temp.setTime(gcor.getTime() - temp.getTime());

var days = Math.floor(temp.getTime() / 86400000);
var hours = temp.getHours();
var minutes = temp.getMinutes();
var seconds = temp.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = 
    (days > 0 ? days+"d " : "") + 
    (hours > 10 ? hours : "0"+hours) + ":" + 
    (minutes > 10 ? minutes : "0"+minutes) + ":" + 
    (seconds == 42 ? "<strong>" + seconds + "</strong>" : (seconds > 10 ? seconds : "0"+seconds));
};

var hUpdate = window.setInterval(update, 1000);
```

Comment: I see, can you make me an example? I'm not really practice with method and similia ^^"

Comment: +1 for "the dom should be only written from the code" although this is not an answer.

Comment: it's just not a good practice to read from the dom - especially reading (and parsing data from a string is highly inperformant).

notice on my edit: it would just be better to Keep the handle to the dom element (received from getElementById) in a var in the outer scope of the update() function. this would also get rid of the handle retrievals on the dom and could be used to determine if the element is still visible on the dom. if it's no longer appended the interval could be abandoned.

Comment: @Daniel, paste the html from your fiddle in the post as well.

Comment: @Dodecapus i added the html before the script